Lazarus Конструктор копирования, копирование объекта в функцию или процедуру
В С++ при копировании объекта в функцию используется конструктор копирования, с помощью него создается копия объекта внутри функции.
Как происходит передача объекта в функцию или процедуру в Lazarus?

В Delphi объекты передаются только по ссылке, в Lazarus логично ожидать такого же поведения

При создании объекта некоего класса с помощью конструктора, переменная данного типа представляет собой указатель. Соответсвенно, в функцию/процедуру передаётся указатель. Если в заголовке функции он был объявлен как const, присвоить ему новое значение невозможно. Но, разумеется, можно использовать свойства и методы объекта. Если он был объявлен как var, то можно этой переменной присвоить новое значение. При этом сам объект не перестанет существовать, т.е. нужно контролировать время жизни.
